# How can you center a list block with no set width?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am dealing with a `UL` block, a nav menu, that can shrink and grow. It's full of list items that are floating leftward, and are user-defined of any length. It has no fixed width, and I cannot alter the HTML or use javascript. All I can do is add CSS. What would be the safest way to center the list?

A quick example of what I have to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/DCYn2/1/
Bear in mind that I can only add CSS. I can't add html, js, or remove existing css.

Comment: You want to center the list itself or the contents of the list?

Comment: Add a snippet of HTML or provide a link to a live example.

Comment: @cimmanon, Apologies. I wish to center the entire list. The UL block. The contents inside grow to fill it. If I can center it without defining width, it'll always sort-of automatically center regardless of contents.

Comment: Perhaps this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally?rq=1) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to center the ul is to change its display property to table and modify the margins.

http://tinker.io/c5ff0

```
ul {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll go ahead with this method.